# DataTables warning: Attempted to initialise DataTables on a node which is not a table: FORM

Tags: jquery-plugins, datatables

I have this error message coming up after I have deployed DataTables inside of my application. I cannot see where this would be coming from as I haven't declared anything in my JS that would cause it. All the tables have got unique names and so do my divs.  I have found this which was the same issue but his workaround doesn't seem to apply to my problem:

http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/7668/datatables-warning-attempted-to-initialise-datatables-on-a-node-which-is-not-a-table-div/p1

Anyone have any pointers?  Google doesn't seem to be able to help so looking at you guys for assistance.

Cheers
Nick

UPDATE:

This is still causing me an issue. could anyone assist or point in the right direction?

Comment: You should post your initialization code and the html for your table, so that others can help you. Are you using an id or a class selector? It's likely you have a duplicate in one of them, so changing your current selector might fix the problem.

Comment: Perhaps this discussion might also be useful: http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/4776/x

Answer (score 3):

You are probably using an id on the datatable whereas you are also declaring another item in the same page with the same id.

I had the same problem:

I had this in my code:

```
<div class="modal fade span3 ui-corner-all" id="cheques" style="display: none">
```

and I also had

```
 <table class="table table-nomargin dataTable table-bordered" id="cheques">
```

I renamed on of the element's id and it worked ;)

Comment: It could also be an attempt to initialise by a class, that is also accidentally a class of the `form` element, in the case of OP.