# How to build data table using Jquery with JSON object

Tags: json, jquery

How to build data table using Jquery with JSON object with specific columns.
My sample JSON object i build at server side is ,

```
Response":{"employeesArray":
            [{"empName":"sarvesh","empId":121,"dept":"Java","salary":"200","exp":2,},
             {"empName":"satish","empId":122,"dept":".net","salary":"200","exp":3}
          ]}
```

Now i want to buid a data table using Jquery with specific columns like emp id, emp name, exp, dept. How can i achieve this one?? There is some thing like this. But i cant understand how to build ?Pleasse help me out.

```
 $('#example').dataTable( {
 } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fillTable(employeesArray){ 
    $('#table').html('');
    $('#table').append(<tr><th>Employee Name</th><th>Employee iD</th><th>Department</th><th>Salary</th><th>Experience</th></tr>);
    for(i in employeesArray){
         $('#table').append(<tr><td>employeesArray[i].empName</td><td>employeesArray[i].empId</td><td>employeesArray[i].dept</td><td>employeesArray[i].salary</td><td>employeesArray[i].exp</td></tr>);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bhuwan thanks for the reply. But here your building table with iteration.I'm expectiong that like below.Why becoz i have to many manipulations on data table                           $(document).ready(function() {
     var oTable = $('#jQueryDataTable').dataTable( {
         "bProcessing": true,
         "sAjaxSource": "/getEmployeesAction.do",
         "aoColumns": [
             { "employeesArray": "empName" },
             { "employeesArray": "empId" },
             { "employeesArray": "salary" },
         ]
     } );
 } )

Comment: When i tried to do like this it is giving alert like "DataTables warning: Attempted to initialise DataTables on a node which is not a table: DIV".

Comment: yes i tried. I checked in below link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443064/datatables-warning-attempted-to-initialise-datatables-on-a-node-which-is-not-a           But i'm having unique id"jQueryDataTable".